# Android: 'dp' to 'px' conversion?

Tags: android, user-interface

I am reading this article: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

It says that the formula Android uses to convert between a **dp** unit to a **px** unit is the following:

```
    px = dp * (dpi / 160)
```

The article also gives an example when the dpi is 240, which gives us px = 1.5 (I'm calculating for one single dp pixel)

However, what exactly does 1.5 mean here? Once the px units are actually the physical device pixels, will Android draw 1 or 2 pixels?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends on the context.

If the *dp* value is used in a context that implies size, like the `android:layout_width` attribute, the logic described for [Resources.getDimensionPixelSize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimensionPixelSize%28int%29) will be used. That is, the *px* value will be rounded to the nearest integer value, with the special case that if *px* > 0, then the actual value will be at least 1.

If the *dp* value is used in a context that implies offset, like the `android:insetLeft` attribute of the Inset Drawable, the logic described for [Resources.getDimensionPixelOffset()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimensionPixelOffset%28int%29) will be used. That is, the *px* value will simply be truncated to an integer value.

Sometimes the unmodified floating point value is used, such as for the `android:dashWidth` attribute of the `<stroke/>` tag in a Shape Drawable, but this is pretty rare. Usually either the size or the offset logic is used, even if the floating point value could be used.

Comment: Humm, that's what I was looking for! I wonder why the documentation doesn't show this... Thanks a lot Martin!

Answer (score 2):

If what I've read is correct, 1.5px means the single '1' pixel is a color specified, and the .5 of a pixel surrounding it will be a blend with the '1' pixel and a pixel next to it.

E.g.

| A | AB | B |

A is 1.5px and B is 1.5x, therefore the pixel in-between is a mixture of both.

So using that, two pixels next to each other will be blended together e.g with a 1px display

| X | Y |

Now with a 1.5px display:

| XY | YX |       It becomes mix of both! but the pixel set as X will be more X than the pixel set as Y

Comment: That's interesting but I think it's not what the article says. It doesn't say anything about colors at all. I guess they just forgot to say what that 1.5 really means. I hate to say this, but this is where I love Apple. Their documentation is so much more accurate!

Comment: Oh, I didn't read it from the Android docs. It's a common feature of a lot of modern OS's and other applications. E.g.typefaces can be 1.5px on the web, and are quite often. The browser calculates a similar thing to what I described.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be the best solution because it's the standard method:

```
int valueInPx= (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, valueInDp, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```